# How to get the list of values in an object if it is greater than specific value using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, underscore.js

I had an object with specific values in it with key and value. I'm trying to pluck all the list by comparing to one of the value in the object.
My object is like

```
var object= {one:1,two:2,three:3,four:4,five:5,six:6,seven:7}
```

Now, i want to pluck all the values which is greater than 3. expected output is like

```
{four:4,five:5,six:6,seven:7}.
```

I'm trying to achieve this using underscore.js.

Comment: What did you do that wasn't working? Wouldn't you just use `omit` or `pick`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_.pick(object, function(value, key, object) {return value > 3;});
```

seems like it should do it, although I haven't tested it.